# Excel - function for a number of matches

Tags: microsoft-excel

If a row or a column contains the cells with the similar data, is there a way to count them up in Excel?

e.g. there are 4 cells in the range.
I need a function to count how many of these 4 cells contain the similar data.

Going a step further, if the contents have double match, (4,4,7,7) is there a way in excel to show it as  for example (2,2)?

So far I have only reached the good old COUNTIF level, giving me a number of specific data matches.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you expand your question to include an example of what you're describing in the first two paragraphs?  It's really too ambiguous for people to be able to help.  What do the cells look like?  What does similar mean?

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't make it more clear. Lets use the poker terminology. I need the function, that could tell me if I have: 1 pair, 2 pair, Three of a kind, Four of a kind.

Comment: What do the cells look like?  What would the output look like?

Comment: Cells are strictly numbers between 1 to 14. There are four cells only and like I mentioned below, using poker terminology I need the returned data to indicate 0 pair, 1 pair, 2 pair, three of a kind, four of a kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective is a little vague, but this may be part of what you want: 
If your data are in `A1:A4`, then set `B1` to

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)=1, COUNTIF(A$1:A$4, A1), "")
```

and drag down to `B4`. 
This says, if we’re looking at the first occurrence of a particular data value,
count all its occurrences, otherwise display blank.  Like this:

[image: 4, 4, 4, 7]       
                        [image: 4, 4, 7, 7]

If you want something more like poker terminology, use

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1)=1,COUNTIF(A$1:A$4, A1)>1), COUNTIF(A$1:A$4, A1), "")
```

which suppresses display of counts that are `1` (i.e., one-of-a-kind):

Three of a kind: [image: 4, 4, 4, 7]        
Two pair: [image: 4, 4, 7, 7] (same as above)

One pair: [image: 2, 5, 7, 7] (example from your comment).

And, to ***really*** use poker terminology, set `B5` to

```
=B1&B2&B3&B4
```

and then set `B6` to

```
=VLOOKUP(B5, G1:H7, 2, FALSE)
```

where `G1:H7` looks like this:

[image: poker hands table]

where

- all of the values in Column `G` are explicitly text;
  e.g., `G1` → `=""`, `G2` → `="2"`, etc..., and
- obviously the last two rows (`23` and `32` → `full house`) are needed
  only if you expand your problem to have five values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helps, however, the repetition of a data could be between the cells A3 and A4. (2,5,7,7). I will check the formula for such cases. Appreciate the response and this valuable tool for me!

Comment: @SKYTTEN: I updated my answer in response to your comments.  (Did the system already tell you that?)

Comment: Thanks again, I just kept visiting this page for any updates, so I got your update (Not through the system, but anyway). This topic has become more fascinating then I would have imagined. I do appreciate your time and effort. Excel capabilities never cease to amaze.